# Create a square with sides at any angle

Tags: python

I am trying to create a rotating turret. The turret rotates correctly the problem is when I make the turret shoot with the space bar the bullet isn't the same size or shape at every angle. I tried using the angle that the turret is facing to do some trig calculations and find the two corner points needed to create the bullet (which is a circle). Nothing I have tried will work. Here is the code:

```
Barrel = [260,210,270,210,270,170,260,170]

def RotateBarrel():
    global angle
    angleChange = 2
    mountCenterX = 265
    mountCenterY = 215
    #Rotate Barrel
    cycle = 1
    while cycle < len(Barrel):
        x = Barrel[cycle-1]-mountCenterX
        y = Barrel[cycle]-mountCenterY
        Barrel[cycle-1] = (x*math.cos(angleChange*math.pi/180)-y*math.sin(angleChange*math.pi/180))+mountCenterX
        Barrel[cycle] = (x*math.sin(angleChange*math.pi/180)+y*math.cos(angleChange*math.pi/180))+mountCenterY
        cycle += 2
    angle += angleChange
    if angle == 360: angle = 0
    canvas.coords(barrel,Barrel)
    self.after(1,RotateBarrel)

def SpinningShoot(event):
    global angle
    speed = 10
    shotXpos = Barrel[6]+10*(math.cos(angle*math.pi/180))
    shotYpos = Barrel[7]-10*(math.sin(angle*math.pi/180))
    cornerX = Barrel[6]+10*(math.cos((90-angle)*math.pi/180))
    cornerY = Barrel[7]-10*(math.sin((90-angle)*math.pi/180))
    shot = canvas.create_oval(shotXpos,shotYpos,cornerX,cornerY,fill="white")
    Xmotion = speed*math.cos(angle*math.pi/180)
    Ymotion = speed*math.sin(angle*math.pi/180) 
    Shots.append(shot)
    ShotsPos.append(shotXpos)
    ShotsPos.append(shotYpos)
    ShotsMotion.append(Xmotion)
    ShotsMotion.append(Ymotion)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your shot is not going to be centered on the "barrel", but the calculation using (90-angle) is going to give you an angular width for the shot of

angle - ( 90  - angle )

which is 2 * angle  - 90

(ie the shot will be wider depending on the size of the angle).

I would have thought use (angle - 45 ) and (angle + 45 ) so your shot is always the same angular width and centered on the barrel.

You would also need to increase the "radius" for the second corner. Im confused about the +10 and -10, not quite sure what they would do.

Probably a better approach is to calculate the "centre" of the bullet and then from that just draw the circle centered on it. Im sure there would be a function that takes the centre and radius. So have

```
radius=10
centrex= radius  * cos ( angle * math.pi /180 )
centrey= radius * sin ( angle * math. pi / 180 )
```

and then pass those two and a radius to a function that does a circle

One other little thing, I would suggest changing the line

```
if angle == 360: angle = 0
```

to

```
if angle >= 360: angle = angle-360
```

as if angle was initialized as anything other than an even number or you changed the angle step you could "miss" the 360 and then never wrap back around.